# JavaScript cumulative sum and list all elements based on two condition

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript,  can anyone try to solve this please thanks in advance

Sample input

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 5},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 15},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 8},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 4}
];
```

expected output : id and item matching record need to sum cumulatively

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 5},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 20},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 8},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 12}
];
```

I tried using the map and reduce function but i am  getting the following output.

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 20},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 12},
];
```

Any ideas how to implement this in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it in place assuming each set of items were in order
If the item is the same as the previous item, sum:

Using for

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 5},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 15},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 8},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 4}
];

for (let i=1; i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i].item === arr[i-1].item) arr[i].total += arr[i-1].total;
}
 

console.log(arr)
```

Using forEach:

```js
var arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 5},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 15},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 8},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 4}
];

arr.forEach((_,i) =>  {
    if (i>0 && arr[i].item === arr[i-1].item) arr[i].total += arr[i-1].total;
})
 

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: May as well use a regular `for` loop if you’re only going to use the index and have to use an `if` to skip index 0, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

This variant creates a copy of the source array with each inner object also copied by [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

In case the summed items are not consecutive, it uses a helper [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) data structure to save the current sum for each connected item (items are considered connected by the `item` field, but it can be changed to `id` field).

For each object, the code checks if the helper has a sum from previous iterations. If so, the sum is added, if no, it adds a 0 for a concise syntax. This check uses [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator).

At last, the current sum is updated in the helper.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 5},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 15},
  {id: 1, item: 'Mango', total: 20},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 8},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 4},
  {id: 2, item: 'Apple', total: 2},
];

const helper = new Map();

const arr2 = arr.map((object) => {
  const objectCopy = { ...object };
  objectCopy.total += helper.get(objectCopy.item) ?? 0;
  helper.set(objectCopy.item, objectCopy.total);
  return objectCopy;
});

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: @user3296668 I've added some more explanations to the answer in case it would be of any help. If you need more, please let me know.